# Cambiar el formato de la fecha que recibo de AAAA-MM-DD a (Febrero 14, 2018)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

tengo una duda.

Se puede cambiar la fecha que recibo de la BD con mi javascript y mostrarla como: "Febrero 14 del 2018", ya que actualmete recibo "2018-02-14"

este es mi **JS**

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'datos.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: {fechas : id},
    dataType: 'json',
    success:function(response) {
        $("#Fecha_ini").html(response.fecha_ini);
        $("#Fecha_fin").html(response.fecha_fin);
    }
});
```

Comment: puedes descomponer la fecha y sustituir los números del mes por su nombre y al final solo concatenas.

Comment: Eso se puede hacer en el mismo javascript ???

Comment: si, permite me preparar una respuesta de como lo puedes hacer

Comment: Mucgas gracias, me ayudaría muchisimo.

Answer (score 5):

Esta podria ser una solucion

```js
// uso el idioma en español
moment.locale('es');
//
var dateTime = moment( '2018-02-14');

var full = dateTime.format('MMMM D, YYYY');

console.log(full);
```

```html
<!-- importo la libreria moments -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<!-- importo todos los idiomas -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.0/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Estimado William; he tratado de llevar tu ejemplo al mio ejemplo: var dateTime = moment(response.fecha_ini);
      $("#Fecha_ini").html(dateTime.format('MMMM D, YYYY')); ... para poder llamarlo a mi html pero no me muestra datos, en que me estoy equivocando.

Answer (score 1):

puedes hacer esto, es bastante rudimentario pero funciona para lo que necesitas

```
var fecha_ini = '2018-02-14';
var fechaPartida = fecha_ini.split('-');
var nombreMeses = ['Enero','Febrero','Marzo','Abril','Mayo','Junio','Julio','Agosto','Septiembre','Octubre','Noviembre','Diciembre'];
var nombreMes = nombreMeses[parseInt(fechaPartida[1])-1];
var fechaTratada = nombreMes +' '+ fechaPartida[2] + ' del ' + fechaPartida[0];
```

espero te sirva.

Comment: He tratado de llevar tu ejemplo al mio ejemplo igual como lo hice con el ejemplo del anterior amigo: var dateTime = moment(response.fecha_ini); $("#Fecha_ini").html(dateTime.format('MMMM D, YYYY')); ... para poder llamarlo a mi html pero no me muestra datos, en que me estoy equivocando.